How to Debug 'Matrix Nearly Singular' error and simulation stuck at 0% in OpenModelica ?"
In the model below, I am simulating a flow that separates into two streams. This is part of a complex model that transitions the inlet flow from 0.25 kg/s to 0.002 kg/s. The simulation consists of three phases:

Gradually apply boundary conditions starting from a quasi-equilibrium state (same pressure, temperature, and flow everywhere).
Find the steady-state solution.
Perform transient analysis.

The model works fine with the steady-state option. However, when using the default option "energyDynamic," I encounter the error "solver total pivot: Matrix nearly singular." Although the solver completes the initialization successfully with 3 homotopy steps, the system gets stuck at 0%.
The "Matrix nearly singular" message is not caused by applying the same pressure across components, as I have tested with gradually varying pressure from the inlet to the outlet and encountered the same issue.
Question :
Using the -LOG_NLS_V option, I obtain the full log information, but I am not familiar with debugging OpenModelica models. What could be the cause of this issue? I am interested in understanding how this problem can be debugged.

Code :
model Test_options

  import Modelica.Constants.pi;
  import Modelica.Blocks.Sources;


  parameter Integer nNodes = 3;
  parameter Real d(unit = "m", displayUnit = "mm") = 11e-3;
  parameter Real D(unit = "m", displayUnit = "mm") = 18e-3;
  parameter Real Ru(unit = "m") = 3.1e-5;

  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;

  replaceable model HeatTransfer_1 = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.ConstantFlowHeatTransfer(alpha0 = 9000);

  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(T_start = 313.15, m_flow_start = 0.3, p_start = 999999.9999999999) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-264, -314}, extent = {{-18, -18}, {18, 18}})));

  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe6(redeclare package Medium = Medium, crossArea = Modelica.Constants.pi*(0.5^2 - 0.3^2), diameter = 0, isCircular = false, length = 140e-3, modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_v_b, nNodes = 1, perimeter = Modelica.Constants.pi*(1 + 0.6), use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-102, -238}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe5(redeclare package Medium = Medium, crossArea = Modelica.Constants.pi*(0.5^2 - 0.3^2), diameter = 0, isCircular = false, length = 140e-3, modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_v_b, nNodes = 1, perimeter = Modelica.Constants.pi*(1 + 0.6), use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-148, -238}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T inlet(redeclare package Medium = Medium, nPorts = 1, use_T_in = false, use_m_flow_in = false, T = 328.15, m_flow = 0.2) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-250, -238}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT outlet(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 431.15, nPorts = 1, use_T_in = false, use_p_in = false, p = 15670000) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {2, -238}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 20e-3, isCircular = true, length = 12e-3) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-210, -238}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 20e-3, isCircular = true, length = 12e-3) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-50, -238}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable table_flow(table = [0, 0.27; 50, 0.45; 166, 0.45; 172, 0.428; 184, 0.363; 196, 0.298; 208, 0.245; 212, 0.227; 218, 0.205; 222, 0.193; 226, 0.18; 232, 0.163; 236, 0.152; 244, 0.135; 254, 0.113; 262, 0.1; 268, 0.09; 272, 0.0846; 282, 0.0729; 296, 0.0576; 306, 0.045; 316, 0.0324; 318, 0.002; 650, 0.002]) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-296, -230}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT p_atm(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 328.15, nPorts = 1, p = 470000, use_T_in = false, use_p_in = false) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {47, -298}, extent = {{11, -12}, {-11, 12}}, rotation = -0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe2(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 20e-3, isCircular = true, length = 12e-3) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-2, -298}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = -0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe7(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 3e-3, length = 2.3, nNodes = nNodes, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-156, -298}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe8(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 3e-3, length = 2.3, nNodes = nNodes, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-106, -298}, extent = {{10, 10}, {-10, -10}}, rotation = 180)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe9(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 3e-3, length = 2.3, nNodes = nNodes, use_HeatTransfer = true) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-56, -298}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = -180)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sensors.TemperatureSensor Temperature3 annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {40, -340}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable Table_Temperature(table = [0, 303.15; 30, 569.03; 600, 569.03]) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {56, -258}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -180)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable Table_pressure(table = [0, 12e+5; 50, 156.7e+5; 600, 156.7e+5]) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {57, -209}, extent = {{-11, -11}, {11, 11}}, rotation = 180)));
equation
  connect(pipe.port_b, pipe5.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-200, -238}, {-158, -238}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe6.port_b, pipe1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-92, -238}, {-60, -238}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(inlet.m_flow_in, table_flow.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-260, -230}, {-285, -230}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(inlet.ports[1], pipe.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-240, -238}, {-220, -238}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe1.port_b, outlet.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-40, -238}, {-6, -238}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(p_atm.ports[1], pipe2.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{36, -298}, {8, -298}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, pipe7.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-200, -238}, {-200, -298}, {-166, -298}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe8.port_a, pipe7.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-116, -298}, {-146, -298}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe2.port_b, pipe9.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-12, -298}, {-46, -298}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe8.port_b, pipe9.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-96, -298}, {-66, -298}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Temperature3.T, p_atm.T_in) annotation(
    Line(points = {{50, -340}, {78, -340}, {78, -293}, {60, -293}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(Temperature3.port, pipe9.heatPorts[3]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{30, -340}, {-56, -340}, {-56, -302}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(pipe5.port_b, pipe6.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-138, -238}, {-112, -238}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(outlet.T_in, Table_Temperature.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{14, -234}, {30, -234}, {30, -258}, {45, -258}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(outlet.p_in, Table_pressure.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{14, -230}, {30, -230}, {30, -209}, {45, -209}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
algorithm

  annotation(
    Line(points = {{-566, -396}, {-556, -396}, {-556, -362}, {-536, -362}, {-536, -356}}, color = {191, 0, 0}),
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")),
    Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-320, -180}, {100, -360}}, initialScale = 0.1)),
    Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-1000, -205}, {425, 100}})),
    version = "");
end Test_options;


Sure you need parameter Real correlatedCoef_BT_separateur[size(Flow_1, 1), 2](each fixed = false);? I had to remove the model to learn that Dymola is also unable to initialize the model...

This parameter is not used in the reduced model, but the complete model needs it to correlate the convection coefficient with the flow.

whitout the "parameter Real correlatedCoef_BT_separateur[size(Flow_1, 1), 2](each fixed = false);" the model will fail to initialize the tables during the initial equations
